# Validating accuracy on time-series data with an atypical ending

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I'm working on a project to predict demand for a product based on past historical data for multiple stores. I have data from multiple stores over a 5 year period. I split the 5-year time series into overlapping subsequences and use the last 18 months to predict the next 3 and I'm able to make predictions. However, I've run into a problem in choosing a cross-validation method.

I want to have a holdout test split, and use some sort of cross-validation for training my model and tuning parameters. However, the last year of the data was a recession where almost all demand suffered. When I use the last 20% (time-wise) of the data as a holdout set, my test score is very low compared to my OOF cross-validation scores, even though I am using a timeseriessplit CV. This is very likely to be caused by this recession being new behavior, and the model can't predict these strong downswings since it has never seen them before.

The solution I'm thinking of is using a random 20% of the data as a holdout, and a shuffled Kfold as cross-validation. Since I am not feeding any information about when the sequence started into the model except the starting month (1 to 12) of the sequence (to help the model explain seasonality), my theory is that the model should not overfit this data based on that. If all types of economy are present in the data, the results of the model should extrapolate to new data too.

I would like a second opinion on this, do you think my assumptions are correct? Is there a different way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your overall assumption is correct in that you can probably take random chunks of time to form your training and testing set. However, when doing it this way, you need to be careful. Rather than predicting the raw values of the next 3 months from the prior 18 months, I would predict the relative increase/decrease of sales in the next 3 months vs. the mean of the past 18 months.

(see here)
http://people.stern.nyu.edu/churvich/Forecasting/Handouts/CourantTalk2.pdf

Otherwise, the correlation between the next 3 months with your prior 18 months data might give you a misleading impression about the accuracy of your model